# Requesting specific part of web resource asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, http, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way of requesting a specific part of a web resource (such as the first 100 bytes) asynchronously from JavaScript?

I'd assumed this could be done through `XmlHttpRequest` by setting its `Range` header. However, if the server applies content-encoding (which most do by default), the byte range would apply to the *encoded* data, not the original. Per [HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35.1):

> When an entity-body is included with a message, the data type of that
> body is determined via the header fields Content-Type and Content-
> Encoding. These define a two-layer, ordered encoding model:

> `entity-body := Content-Encoding( Content-Type( data ) )`

> Byte range specifications in HTTP apply to the sequence of bytes in
> the entity-body […].

This renders the retrieved content useless, since it cannot be decoded without retrieving (and concatenating) the rest of the encoded resource.

It is apparently not possible to disable content-encoding from the client-side, since `XMLHttpRequest` [prohibits](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) the `Accept-Encoding` from being changed.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { /* ... */ };
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-99");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity");  // not allowed
xhr.send();
```

Is there another way of achieving this (assuming content-encoding cannot be disabled on the server)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using old style techniques of simulating ajax behaviour like loading hidden iframe with all headers that you mention(and probably the encoding header will be allowed) and getting data from such hidden iframe. Here is example for uploading multipart data using hidden iframe: [example](https://gist.github.com/corsonx/8355590). You could change it for your needs. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll investigate whether it can emit the `Accept-Encoding: identity` header and post back.